# is it possible to use a stem part of multiple xpaths to create a program to randomly selects one?(selenium)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use a stem part of multiple xpaths to create a program to randomly selects one?

Say for example we are given these multiple xpaths:

```
//a[@href='/colour/red/yellow']

//a[@href='/colour/red/blue']

//a[@href='/colour/blue/ornage']

//a[@href='/colour/yellow/green']
```

Is it possible to randomly select one of the xpaths by using part of the xpath in a code, e.g:

```
option1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("part of xpath")
```

I know this line of code wont work, but is there a specific function to use instead of **`browser.find_element_by_xpath`**

I am a beginner at programming pls help.

**[EDIT]: I have found this function instead:**

```
find_element_by_partial_link_text('')
```

**I'm not sure how this function works, but would i be able to use this instead on links of each example, e.g:**

- we are given the site: http://www.colour.com/colour/ (Not real site)
- and a link to part of the website is: http://www.colour.com/colour/red/yellow
- and a link to another part of the website is: http://www.colour.com/colour/red/blue

I want a code that randomly picks between both parts of site, could i use something similar to:

```
option1 = find_element_by_partial_link_text('http://www.colour.com/colour/red')
```

- My point more specifically is to use part of link, and let program search the website for possible full links, and randomly select one.

Is this even possible?

**[UPDATE]:**
**Breaks Software's solution worked**; it has allowed me to use part of link, e.g. http://www.colour.com/colour/red

The program its self would then make a decision between:

http://www.colour.com/colour/red/yellow

and http://www.colour.com/colour/red/blue

Code:

```
#open website
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('http://www.colour.com/colour'))
from random import randint

#generating program to select random link
target_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='/colour/red")

random_index = randint(0, len(target_links) - 1)
target_links[random_index].click()
```

Thank you for everyone's help, I hope this question can help others facing similar problem.

Comment: Do you want to use one of those XPath expressions or add color to XPath template like `//a[@href='/colour/{some_color}/{another_color}']`?

Comment: Considering your edit: NO, it's not possible: you want to handle link **references** (e.g.  http://www.colour.com/colour/red ) while `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` should receive part of link **text** (e.g. `"Yellow"` from  [YellowStone](http://somelink.com) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are asking to find all of the links that start with a particular URL, then randomly choose one of them to follow.

```
target_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='http://www.colour.com']")

random_index = randint(0, len(target_links) - 1)
target_links[random_index].click()
```

alternatively, you could look for the links that contain the partial path "colour" with the CSS selector:

```
a[href*='/colour/']
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much. This is what I have tried to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
from random import randint

color_list = ('yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'green')

list_len = len(color_list)
myrandint = randint(0, list_len -1)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/colour/"+color_list[myrandint]+"/"+color_list[myrandint]+"']")
print(test)
```

Or

```
from random import randint

my_list = (
   "//a[@href='/colour/red/yellow']",
   "//a[@href='/colour/red/blue']",
   "//a[@href='/colour/blue/ornage']",
   "'//a[@href='/colour/yellow/green']"
)

list_len = len(color_list)
myrandint = randint(0, list_len -1)

browser.find_element_by_xpath(my_list[myrandint])
```

Comment: Both methods are great, thanks bro. however i was wandering if i could use main part of xpath to make a random decision between diff option. e.g. "//a[@href='/colour/red/yellow']",
   "//a[@href='/colour/red/blue']", could i use part of the xpath like "//a[@href='/colour/red/']" to make random choice

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use below code:

```
import random

list_of_xpath = ["//a[@href='/colour/red/yellow']",
                "//a[@href='/colour/red/blue']",
                "//a[@href='/colour/blue/ornage']",
                "//a[@href='/colour/yellow/green']"]
option1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(random.choice(list_of_xpath))
```

Or if you need just some random combination of colors in your XPath:

```
colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'green']
xpath = "//a[@href='/colour/{0}/{1}']".format(random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors))
option1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question,

- The first question *Is it possible to use a stem part of multiple xpaths to create a program to randomly selects one?* Answer is **Yes**
- The second question *Is it possible to randomly select one of the xpaths?* Doesn't seems to me a valid usecase because if you select a random `xpath` you won't be able to `Assert`/`validate` further.
- As per the first question a solution would be to pass the intended choice of colour to navigate and you can write a function as follows :

  ```
  def test_url(choiceColour):
      option1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '" + choiceColour + "')]")
  ```
- Incase you want to pass two colours of your choice you can write a function as follows :

  ```
  def test_url(firstColour, secondColour):
      option1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '" + firstColour + "') and contains(@href, '" + secondColour + "')]")
  ```
- Now you can call either of these functions from your `main()`/`@Test` method as per your requirement.

  > **Note** : Incase of the function def `test_url(firstColour, secondColour)` passing **/colour/red/yellow** or **/colour/yellow/red** may identify the same element.